# Claims for authenticating 3rd party with JWT

Tags: cloud, bearer-token, jwt

We have designed a workflow for enabling 3rd party systems (1) to use ours (2) without need of extra authentication, as depicted here:

[image: JWT workflow]

Here is the description:

1. The 3rd party client application (web) wants to launch our application. It requests a token to its own backend.
2. The 3rd party backend generates a JWT with a random token value, associated to the current user
3. The 3rd party backend sends the JWT to our system through a specific API
4. After registered, the JWT is sent back to the 3rd party client application (web)
5. The 3rd party app launches our client application (web) passing the JWT
6. Our application calls our backend API's by using the registered JWT

The questions are the following:

- If this workflow is valid/usual
- What are the correct claims to use in the JWT for user_email, organization_id, token

Comment: The JWT tokens are plain json with hash. So I would suggest again `user_email` as part of JWT, I prefer to use UUIDs which represent the user. Also I would suggest you to use different key for each 3rd party. So tokens generated by you and 3rd party should have different hashes and also you needs to have a field saying which client has generated the JWT to differentiate. Rest your architecture looks good as such

Comment: I am wondering how the expiration time is handling in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IANA Token Claims registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml#claims) is supposed to be the source of standard JWT claims. If yours are not listed - it can be anything but you probably want to minimise potential clashes with additional namespacing.

**UPD** *it appears I misinterpreted the question and you are rather providing an API for users that have been authorised by 3rd party. I deleted oAuth part which seems irrelevant now*

As I suggested in comments, JWT comes with a signature which your backend can verify using 3rd party's public keys. This way you eliminate a couple of extra API calls to set everything up.

Given you opt for that, the flow can be like so:

1. The 3rd party client application (web) wants to launch our application. It requests a token to its own backend.
2. The 3rd party backend generates a JWT with correct `issuer`, `audience` other  required claims and signs it with their private key
3. The 3rd party backend returns the signed JWT to the client
4. The 3rd party app launches our client application (web) passing the JWT
5. Our application calls our backend API's by using the registered JWT (the backend will verify token signature using token issuer and 3rd party public key).

Validation is [part of the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515.html) so most libraries will handle this for you with minimal configuration.
Just be aware of known JWT/JWT validation issues and mitigate them on your side.

Comment: Hi @timur, you are starting from an incorrect premise: it is not our user. The whole purpose is to enable the 3rd party to launch our application for their users without having to login into our system. At least not through the frontend.

Comment: Right. So you trust 3rd parties enough to authorise any user they give you? In this case maybe have 3rd parties generate a signed jwt (for you as audience) with required claims and verify it comes from said 3rd parties? I'll update the answer once I get onto a proper computer.

Comment: yes, it is a B2B connection (under an agreement). We can verify it comes from some specific secured server. Thanks.